# RxJava emit after timeout, keep observable active

Tags: java, rx-java2, reactivex

How could I do something like this:

I have an observable that emits some result I load from an API. This is mapped into an `ResultObject` that holds a state (loading, success, error) and the object or an error (I don't want to emit an error because this observable will update again).

For now, I merge two observables, one just emitting an `ResultObject` with state `loading` and the observable that really loads the data and then emits an `ResultObject` with state `success`.

Usually, if in a fast network, that loading part is quite fast, so the UI reacts to the `loading` state, shows that for a few hundred millisecounds and then shows the data. Does not look that nice.

Now I want to show that loading indicator just, if the data loading takes longer than a second.

Before I fix that on UI side, I thought to ask this here:

Is there a possibility, to have an observable, have an operator that does something like this:

```
myObservable
    .emitAfterTimeout(1000, new ResultObject(LOADING)
```

The normal `timeout` operator does not help, because I need to keep the observable active, I want to have the result anyway.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could use a `debounce` on the `Observable`.

Comment: @flakes you mean a debounce of 1 second on the merged observable? Hm, but that would also mean, if my result comes very fast, I still have to wait one second for it...

Comment: Yup, but If you complete the observable after the success, then the result will be emitted immediately upon completion.

Comment: @flakes Problem is: Good idea... If I flatMap that correctly I will get what I want I think. Will try that. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Good luck!